# Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.8.0 at specified path

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

When building my Jenkins job I get the following error message:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project data-script-tests: Could not
> resolve dependencies for project
> com.arkana:data-script-tests:jar:0.0.2: Could not find artifact
> com.sun:tools:jar:1.8.0 at specified path C:\Program
> Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251/../lib/tools.jar

I verified that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251/ do exist on build machine.

However, tools.jar is really missing.

What's the reason? How can I solve this?

Comment: Install a SDK instead of a JRE

Answer (score 2):

As Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen said, you need a JDK instead of a JRE.

JREs cannot be used to build a Java project, only to run it.

Comment: Thank you. I installed the JDK as you suggested, and tools.jar is really under C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\lib. However, Jenkins still searches it under the JRE directory (as listed in the question above). I checked and there is no mention of version 251 in the environment variables. JAVA_HOME is set to jdk1.8.0_171 anyways...

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Jenkins configuration setting was to use the System JDK which was 8.
However, I should have set the JDK setting to 15.
Once I did that, everything worked.